# Spyder Plotly - multiple plots in one browser window

Tags: python, plotly, spyder

If I have multiple plotly figures within Spyder IDE how can I display them all on one browser window?

E.g. if I run the below code it opens two charts on two separate windows, whereas I want them on one page, one after the other:

```
fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
fig_1 = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 2, 5, 7, 9])

plot(fig)
plot(fig_1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`make_subplots`](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/):

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

fig.append_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16],
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1,
)

fig.append_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        y=[0, 2, 5, 7, 9],
    ),
    row=2,
    col=1,
)

fig.show()
```

[image: subplots]

Alternatively you could use plotly dash to create more complex layouts and dashboards.